# Stochastic calculus with normal distribution

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

For $l=1,2......$ prove that  $E[W^{2l+1} (t)]=0$

I am trying to find the ways of solving the task from Stochastic calculus, but it seems to be very difficult to start with.

I am really appreciate any hints and thoughts about solution.

Comment: As you might know $W(t)  \sim N(0,t)$. Fortunately, there is general formula for the (central) moments of the normal distribution. See for instance
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments

Note: perhaps it's useful to change the title of this topic as well since its not very specific.

Comment: $W(t)$ is distributed as $N(0,t)$ which is an even distribution. Thus the odd moments are the integral of an odd function which is zero provided it makes sense.